# Freezing Issue in OpenCV: waitKey(1) Paired with Lengthy Calculations Between Frames

Tags: python, opencv

I'm attempting to process a video frame by frame, and my goal is to perform a specific action for the frames while a key is held down. The problem is that while a key is held down the images stop updating in the cv2 window. This only appears to happen when there is a large calculation for each frame. Below is code that reproduces my issue:

```
import time
import cv2
import traceback

# Start video capture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

try:
    # Loop through the video frames
    while cap.isOpened():
        # Read a frame from the video
        success, frame = cap.read()

        # Break the loop if the end of the video is reached
        if not success: break

        # if the following time.sleep is commented out, it works as intended
        time.sleep(1) # simulate long calculation

        cv2.imshow("", frame) # PROBLEM: When a key is held down the images stop updating
        print('update image') # this still outputs to the console every second

        # Break the loop if 'q' is pressed
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        print(key) # this still outputs what key is being pressed every second
        if key == ord("1"):
            pass # preform action while certain key is held down
        if key == ord("q"):
            break

except Exception as err:
    traceback.print_exc()
finally:
    # Release the video capture object and close the display window
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've updated my opencv version (I'm now using 4.8.1.78) but it did not fix the issue. I've also looked up similar issues online but can't find anything helpful.

Comment: Don't do that :) At least from Windows UI perspective, this is not surprising. You're flooding the message queue with keyboard messages, process it only once a second, and stop processing after the first keyboard message is found. IIRC paint events only get generated by the system when the queue is empty, and you're filling it faster than you can empty it. Hence, it never gets to a point where it could actually repaint the window. |  Generally, lengthy calculations shouldn't be done in the GUI thread, if you want the GUI to stay responsive.

Comment: You can try emptying all the pending keypress events by running [`pollKey`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga6d20fbd3100ec3badc1eaa653aff99d7) in a loop (at appropriate time).

Comment: @DanMašek That's such a simple fix, I can't believe I couldn't figure that out. Thank you for the clear explanation and quick response! While this is a good workaround, how would you recommend moving the lengthy calculations out of the GUI thread?